# How do I retrieve the Name of the User using SPServices given the email address?

Tags: spservices

Is it possible to retrieve the name of a user using the SPServices given the email address?

Suppose Jack Harry has a email `jack_harry@goodworld.net` inside the SharePoint 2007. Is it possible to provide SPService the email `jack_harry@goodworld.net` and SPServices will return `Jack Harry`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetUserLoginFromEmail",
    emailXml: "<Users><User Email='jack_harry@goodworld.net'/></Users>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("User").each(function() {
                    $(this).attr("DisplayName");
                })
        }
});
```

Comment: +1 David, you are awesome!

Comment: Excellent Answer

Comment: Every time I try to pull the responseText from the result, it gives me null value for some reason. How do you get the display Name from all this. Cause it returns an object and during run time the responseText is absent